What is the correct way to think of position?
How accurate would it be to think of position (along some axis) as the component of radius vector. Example:
$$ \textbf{r} = x \hat{\textbf{i}} + y \hat{\textbf{j}} $$
And if that is correct, we could find $x$ component velocity of motion in 1D by using this formula:
$$v_x = \dfrac{dx}{dt} $$
By solving the differential equation for $x$ component of position vector, (in the case of constant velocity) we get:
$$ \Delta{x} = v \int_{0}^{t}{dt} = vt $$
Which is a very well-known equation in kinematics. My question is: did I understand this correct?
Note: j component of radius vector is unnecessary in 1D motion. I wanted to write the more general form of equation, hence I included it.

Indeed. In many Physics textbooks position is assumed to be a vector in 3D space, defined as :
$$ \textbf{r} = x \hat{\textbf{i}} + y \hat{\textbf{j}} + z \hat{\textbf{k}} \tag 1$$
then velocity is derivative of position vector ,
$$ \textbf{v} = \frac{d}{dt} \textbf{r} =  \frac{d}{dt} \left(x \hat{\textbf{i}} + y \hat{\textbf{j}} + z \hat{\textbf{k}}\right) = \hat{\textbf{i}}\frac{dx}{dt} + \hat{\textbf{j}}\frac{dy}{dt}  +\hat{\textbf{k}} \frac{dz}{dt} = v_x\hat{\textbf{i}} + v_y\hat{\textbf{j}}  +v_z\hat{\textbf{k}} \tag 2$$
Then from (2) we can deduce that,
$$ d \textbf{r} = \textbf v dt \tag 3$$
And integrating that get change in position,
$$ \int_{r_1}^{r_2} d \textbf{r} = \int_0^T \textbf v dt \tag 4,$$
assuming velocity constant we get,
$$ \textbf r_2 - \textbf r_1 = T\textbf v. $$

Note that this only works if the unit vectors $\hat{\textbf{i}}$ etc. are constant. If the co-ordinate axes are changing e.g. the co-ordinate frame is rotating then there will be extra terms in the expression for $\textbf v$.

Yes. I have assumed that coordinate frame is fixed. Otherwise we would need to perform differential multiplication rule $d(uv)=udv+vdu$ with $d(x \hat{\textbf{i}})$ and so on. Thanks.

Yes, that's correct. Position is a point in $n$-space, and velocity is its derivative. Integrating velocity, you get the change in position, a.k.a. displacement.
Formally, position is $\vec r=x\vec{\mathrm{i}}+y\vec{\mathrm{j}}+z\vec{\mathrm{k}}$ (or any other linear combination of basis vectors depending on what your coordinate system/spatial dimension count is), velocity is $\vec v=\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec r}{\mathrm{d}t}$, and displacement from $t=a$ to $t=b$ is $\mathrm{d}\vec r=\int_a^b\vec v\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_a^b\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec r}{\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}t$.
For two dimensions, you just have position being a pair $(x,y)$. Maybe more commonly, you can also use a triplet for 3D space: position is then $(x,y,z)$. Less commonly, in relativity especially, we add time as another dimension, so "positions" become "events" with positions in space and time, represented by the pair $(t,x,y,z)$ (or $(x,y,z,t)$ if you don't conform to the zero-index standard). This is called a 3+1-dimensional point, since it has 3 "spatial" dimensions and one "temporal" dimension. Indeed, in all cases cases, the radius vector is defined with these coordinates, with $\vec r=x\vec{\mathrm{i}}+y\vec{\mathrm{j}}+z\vec{\mathrm{k}}$, so it is accurate to say that position coordinates are encoded within the radius vector as you suggest.
